# Strictly increasing sequences of positive integers

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be nonnegative integers. Suppose the number of strictly increasing sequences of integers $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{2014}$ satisfying $0 \leq a_m \leq 3m$ is $2^\alpha (2\beta + 1)$. Find $\alpha$.

We need $0 \leq a_0 \leq 0, 0 \leq a_1 \leq 3, 0 \leq a_2 \leq 6,\ldots,0 \leq a_{2014} \leq 6042$. We also need to make sure that the sequence is strictly increasing. How do we count the number of sequences with both conditions satisfied?

Comment: It is probably more useful to write it as $0 \leq a_0 \leq 0$ and then $a_0 < a_1 \leq 3$ and then $a_1 < a_2 \leq 6$ ... $a_{2013} < a_{2014} \leq 6042$. That way, we incorporate both the strictly increasing and $0 \leq a_m \leq 3m$ conditions into one.

Comment: Um...Maybe I messed up, but I am getting that this problem grows ridiculously fast. Like, if we change the problem from $a_{2014}$ to $a_{150}$, I get $22009727622661468914354672187087200365176573317993759756821591780069039222038370990489754667881865932423581625413475308064$ different possibilities.

Comment: The sequence is [OEIS A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764) where it says $a(n)=\frac 1{3n+1}{3n+1 \choose n}$ and gives the asmyptotic $a(n)\sim 3^(3*n+1/2)/(\sqrt(\pi)*4^(n+1)*n^(3/2))$

Comment: @RossMillikan That's really cool! It also matches up with my findings through my algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do this by induction.

Base Case: There is $1$ possibility for a sequence with only $a_0$, which is $a_0=0$.

Induction: Let's say there are $n_l$ possibilities for $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_m$ where $a_m=l$. Then, there are $n_l$ more possibilities for $a_{m+1}=l+1$, $n_l$ more possibilities for $a_{m+1}=l+2$, $n_l$ more possibilities for $a_{m+1}=l+3$, and so on and so on until $n_l$ more possibilities for $a_{m+1}=3m+3$. Thus, every possibility added to $a_{m+1}=k$ is also added to $a_{m+1}=k-1$ except for $a_m=k-1$, which is only added to the former. This means the possibilities for $a_{m+1}=k$ is that of $a_{m+1}=k-1$ plus that of $a_m=k-1$.

Through this reasoning, we can create an algorithm to find how many possibilities there are for $a_{2014}$ by summing up all of the $n_l$ for $m=2014$.

```
# last_posses[k] is the number of satisfying sequences a_0 -> a_{m-1} such that a_{m-1}=k
last_posses = []
# Set the base case for m=0
last_posses.append(1)
# Go from m=1 to m=2015
for m in range(1, 2015):
    # new_posses[k] is the number of satisfying sequences a_0 -> a_m such that a_m=k
    # For k=0, the number of possibilities is 0 for m > 0
    new_posses = [0]
    # Set the number of possibilities for a_m=k to that of a_{m-1}=k-1 and a_m=k-1
    for k in range(1, 3*m+1):
        last_posses_k_1 = 0
        if k-1 < len(last_posses): last_posses_k_1 = last_posses[k-1]
        new_posses.append(last_posses_k_1+new_posses[k-1])
    # Print the possibilities for a_m
    print(m, sum(new_posses))
    # Finally, set last_posses for the next value of m:
    last_posses = new_posses
```

For $m=2014$, we get the answer of:
$$3009446811626840011516401963155702629124902852118283105566646499187975210483977568037240534936862340607729836441886154443644457159609713018147993750244671611748779116663020368670227389102377986142966479184505943056015364354657062572078398141165875031835225054200848325595952700574080052386052827533191994070941546059814026835313797732981339424675440290526207968686939017841145279975794797532005989737772818590520465194506778810650848615074684190259589599538263376333059235354387470289701424649773613907313946729873461448708050494821314469268590045593768487443749727621955255063798096707855894951247650161148672847306458557801371580447356889909515455870356964721466202827707402679124377010560546648288947302852927912382188712062602374803794875194894365603063572738782017918976136321536693045645468425066500059809139220874911575512154181026459279040907393951629466087671002174985212405077254937440451018499020932159879407769193869346405952943115842638902338373130068734671319711391418864018167911980296303477552046569058688208640626392046293346706878531801986277274285765289069443500847583518238303120633029907590423170043641958401331997519193423480232780275170254564112609317443216698185135492771835617570005974205482943655701557644907933960865336151469323207300899509253042454586178298685009245551330879878830257823136950961130194691211959442383090119736071839205553728259015562612039749660442822914977645987566685726864300272095156071142537162111858786957898766632031174610898166685776902818189483414850729733763292271633425389274136887952707739210658112190892922296545082192770266062754108475025626815589361509266684815729837638626786357897654553914766152389941248$$
The biggest power of $2$ that divides this number is $2^{11}$ (which can be easily found by guess and check by using a Python shell to divide this number by powers of 2), so $\alpha=11$.

Comment: A hint given to this problem was to use Catalan numbers.

Comment: @user19405892 Here is [the answers for $m=1$ to $m=50$](http://pastebin.com/raw/g1sNjR4t). Hopefully, someone can go off this and using Catalan numbers, try to solve the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The number of increasing sequences $a_0,a_1,\dots, a_n$ such that $a_k\leq 3k$ is clearly $\binom{3(n+1)}{n+1}/(2n+3)$.

From here we use polignac's formula to find $v_2$.

We have $v_2(\binom{3\times 2015}{2015}/(2(2014)+3))=v_2(3\times2015)!-v_2(2\times 2015)!-v_2(2015)!$.

Using polignac's formula this is equal to:

$6036-4020-2005=11$.

(instead of using polignac's formula we could also have used kummer's theorem).

Comment: The answer is $10$.

Comment: are you sure?${}{}$

Comment: notice that the sequence has $2015$ terms.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I am also getting $\alpha=11$ through my improved algorithm.

Comment: @NobleMushtak good to hear.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Could you explain the division by $2n+3$ in your first line?

Comment: sure, you want lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,2n+2)$ such that the excedence is $0$, since the excedence can take on each of the values $0,1,2,\dots,2n+2$ with equal probability we must divide by $2n+3$.